# "Не видны" объекты WP

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Пишу плагин для ВП. Есть основной файл `custom-registration.php` из которого идет вызов другого `obrab.php`:

```
<span onclick="loadHTML(\''.plugins_url("custom-registration/obrab.php").'?item=0\',\'content\')">Телефон</span>
```

В `obrab.php` происходит сортировка таблицы и вывод ее.

Проблема - в файле obrab.php "не видны" объекты ВордПресса.

Этот код

```
global $wpdb;
$quest_user_arr = $wpdb->get_results( .... );
```

выдает ошибку:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function get_results() on a non-object in ...
```

Как заставить видеть объекты ВП в файле `obrab.php`? Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь вызвать `obrab.php` из javascript. При этом инициализация WP не происходит. ajax в WP работает только при соблюдении определенных правил.

О принципах построения ajax в WP можно почитать [здесь](https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html).

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйста. Здесь принято отмечать ответ, который помог, как принятый (зеленая галка). Это поможет ориентироваться другим пользователям, которые ищут ответ на похожий вопрос.